# How to change dll location to subdirectory in Codelite?

Tags: c++, dll, wxwidgets, codelite

Im using Codelite IDE and build test.exe gui application. When i started application i got error that some dlls missing. I found all that dll and put in folder where is test.exe, and all is working now. But with all that dlls there is mess in main folder.

How to move that dlls to sub directory so application still work, except i add that folder in PATH?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the `PATH` environment variable
To make it work in CodeLite, add line similar to this from: `Settings->Environment variables`

`PATH=$PATH;C:\Path\To\My\Dll\Folder`

Ofc, replace `C:\Path\To\My\Dll\Folder` to the actual path where you want your DLLs to be placed

Eran

Answer (score 0):

Try this work-around:

Right click to your **project** - **settings** - **general**.

Change the "Executable to Run / Debug" to:

`$(ProjectPath)/$(IntermediateDirectory)/$(ProjectName)`

Change the "Working Directory" to:

`$(ProjectPath)/YOUR DLL DIRECTORY`